# How to enter date in excel with python with scheduling time?

Tags: python, excel, date

Whenever the date changes, I want to enter it in Excel.
How can I make my code executes once per day?

[image]

```
import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook


now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowDate = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.active
sheet1.title = 'sampleSheet'

sheet1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = nowDate

wb.save(filename='test.xlsx')
```

Comment: you want to execute the script once per day ?

Comment: Yeah! once a day!

Comment: i edited your question to make it more clear, and i hope i answered your question, check and tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's really simple using 'scheduling', but please notice you must keep your script running all the time here is the code :

```
import datetime
import schedule
import time

from openpyxl import Workbook

def my_function ():
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   nowDate = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   wb = Workbook()
   sheet1 = wb.active
   sheet1.title = 'sampleSheet'
   sheet1.cell(row=1, column=1).value = nowDate
   wb.save(filename='test.xlsx')

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(my_function)

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

for more info check the following tutorial with examples : [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs5jGDROx1M)

Answer (score 1):

If this script is being run once per day with the same Excel file, you could check if the date already exists in any of the previous cells and if not, write it.